# How to keep flutter application awake although user or OS switches off the screen?

Tags: flutter, background, sleep

I have an flutter application designed to run for a long time on the user tablet/smartphone to share the user location while doing his activities.
My need is to have the application running in backgroud even if the smartphone is in sleep mode (screen switched off).
Currently, it seems that when the screen switches off, the application is running about one more minute, and then stops by itself and no longer shares the expected position.

I've read and tried wakelock (https://pub.dev/packages/wakelock) but this package prevents from screen to switch off, but I do want to allow the screeen to switch off (to preserve battery).

Answer (score 0):

iOS generally does not allow apps to do work in the background. There are only certain scenarios which can be implemented. See the [iOS Documentation about background modes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/configuring-background-execution-modes) for details.
ie. possible solutions depend on your use case.